# Multiple background colors for events in timeGridWeek and timeGridDay

Tags: events, fullcalendar, background-color

We have a requirement for our calendar to display events that might have a start and end buffer.  We would like the buffers to be a different color from the primary event color.  For example, let's say I have a basketball game that starts at 5pm and ends at 8pm.  It's possible that event has a 30 minute start and 90 minute stop buffer applied.  We would like for the calendar event to display starting at 5pm and ending at 8pm.  On the timeGridWeek and timeGridDay views, we would like for this particular event to have grey representing the start buffer (4:30pm - 5pm) and stop buffers (8pm - 9:30pm), and the primary event would have a different color from 5pm - 8pm.

We looked at the FullCalendar docs and it looks like we can get the view type in our custom event React component which we think will be helpful.  But it wasn't obvious to us how to create an Event as described above.

I've attached an image that we mocked up that hopefully makes it more obvious.

[image: Event Mockup]

Has anyone ever done something like this?  Any pointers would be awesome!  Thank you.

Louis

Comment: I think for this you'd actually just create 3 separate events, maybe linked with a groupId

Comment: Yeah, we thought about that.  Probably is the best option.  Appreciate the feedback!